# How to force a for loop counter to skip iterations in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I recently ran into an issue where I was using a for loop somewhat similar to this:

```
for i in range(lineCount(fileToBeProcessed)):
    print(i)
    j = doSomeStuff() #returns number of lines in the file to skip
    i = i+j
    print(i)
    print('next_loop')
```

For a value of `j={2,3,1}` the output was:

```
1
3
next_loop
2
5
next_loop
.
.
```

My desired output:

```
1
3
next_loop
4
7
next_loop
.
.
```

Every time the next iteration started, the for loop counter `i` reset to the original cycle. My question is, is there a way to force the for loop to skip the iterations based on the return value `j`. I understand and was able to implement something similar with a while loop. However, I was curious as to how or why would Python not allow such manipulation?

Comment: This is a job for a `while`, not a `for`.

Comment: use the `continue` keyword with some condition

Comment: You might also directly iterate `fileToBeProcessed` (or an `enumerate` of the same) and call `next` on the iterator to skip elements.

Answer (score 3):

It allows manipulations. But a `for` loop in Python works with a:

```
for <var> in <iterable>:
    # ...
```

So Python does **not** attaches a special meaning to `range(n)` as a `for` loop: a `range(n)` is an **iterable** that iterates from `0` to `n` (exclusive). At the end of each iteration the *next* element of the iterable. It furthermore means that once you constructed a `range(n)`, if you **alter `n`, it has no impact on the `for` loop**. This in contrast with for instance Java, where `n` is evaluated each iteration again.

Therefore you can manipulate the variable, but after the end of the loop, it will be assigned the next value of the loop.

In order to manipulate the variable, you can **use a `while` loop**:

```
i = 0 # initialization
while i < lineCount(fileToBeProcessed): # while loop
    print(i)
    j = doSomeStuff() #returns number of lines in the file to skip
    i = i+j
    print(i)
    print('next_loop')
    i += 1 # increment of the for loop is explicit here
```

Usually a `while` loop is considered to be "less safe" since you have to do the increment yourself (for all code paths in the loop). Since it is something one tends to forget, it is easier to write an endless loop.

Comment: That is exactly, why I wanted to use a for loop. I kept running into endless while loops in order to implement it in `while` instead of `for`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `fileToBeProcessed` is actually a file-like object, you can iterate directly over the file (i.e. over the lines in that file), or use `enumerate(fileToBeProcessed)` if you need the line numbers, and call `next` on that iterator to skip lines.

Like this (not tested):

```
iterator = enumerate(fileToBeProcessed) # or just iter = fileToBeProcessed
for i, line in iterator:
    print(i)
    j = doSomeStuff() #returns number of lines in the file to skip
    for _ in range(j):
        i, line = next(iterator) # advance iterator -> skip lines
    print(i)
    print('next_loop')
```

Comment: Alternatively, instead of the nested for loop to advance the stream, you could use the `islice` function in `itertools` like so: (`islice(j)`)

Answer (score 0):

I've edited the code hope it may help

```
z =0
for i in range(lineCount(fileToBeProcessed)):
    if i <= z: #if i is a value that you don't want to be output, then skip loop to next one
        continue
    print(i)
    j = doSomeStuff()
    cnt += 1
    z = i+j #use a different variable from i since i the iterator value will not be updated
    print(z)
    print('next_loop')
```